# Mi metodo estatico no modifica una variable estática, por qué?

Tags: java, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Estoy tratando de implementar una pila (stack) básica. Añadí los métodos push(), pop(), size(), resize() y peek(). Sin embargo, al utilizarlos, la variable estática N que deberia guardar el indice siguiente en el cual se añadira un nuevo elemento a la pila, no esta siendo modificado por push(). Por ejemplo, al hacer push de un elemento coloqué N++ al final del metodo push(), pero N sigue valiendo 0 siempre. Es decir, el indice N no se recorre. En que me falló? Ya le di muchas vueltas y no supe.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stackk {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Este programa apila elementos en una stack.");

    int[]stack=new int[1];
    int N = 0;
    
    String accion;
    boolean continuar = true;
    while (continuar){
        
        accion = preguntarAccion();    
    
        switch(accion){
            case "push": push(stack, N);
                break;
            case "pop": pop(stack, N);
                break;  
            case "peek": peek(stack, N);
                break;   
            case "size": size(stack, N);
                break;   
          
        }
        System.out.println("N vale " + N);
        System.out.println("El stack contiene: " + Arrays.toString(stack));
        continuar = deseaContinuar();
    }
    System.out.println("El programa terminó. Adiós!");
}

    public static String preguntarAccion(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese 1 si desea pushear un objeto nuevo en la stack");
        System.out.println("Ingrese 2 si desea sacar el ultimo elemento que se añadió a la stack");
        System.out.println("Ingrese 3 si desea saber cual es el elemento en el tope de la stack");
        System.out.println("Ingrese 4 si desea saber el numero de elementos en la stack");
        
        int decision = teclado.nextInt();
        String decisionTomada="";
        switch(decision){
            case 1: decisionTomada = "push";
                       break;
            case 2: decisionTomada = "pop";
                       break;
            case 3: decisionTomada = "peek";
                       break;
            case 4: decisionTomada = "size";
                       break;
        }
        return decisionTomada;
    }    

      public static void push(int[]a, int N){
          if (N == a.length){
              a = resize(a,N);
          }
          Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Eligió la opción push. Ingrese el elemento que desea añadir a la stack: ");
          int elementoNuevo=teclado.nextInt();
          a[N]=elementoNuevo;
          System.out.println("Se añadió el elemento " + elementoNuevo + " a la stack.");
          N++;
      }

        public static boolean deseaContinuar(){
            boolean continuar = true;    
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Desea continuar? Presione 1 para continuar, presione 2 para detener el programa");
            int deseaContinuar = teclado.nextInt();
            switch(deseaContinuar){
                case 1 : break;
                case 2 : continuar = false;
                              break;
            }
            return continuar;
        }
        
        public static int[] resize(int[]a, int N){
                int[]aux = new int[(int)1.25*N];
                for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
                    aux[i]=a[i];
                }
        return aux;
        }
        
        public static int pop(int[]a,int N){
            int elementoTope = a[N];
            if (N == 0){
                System.out.println("No puede sacar ningún elemento, no hay ningún elemento en la pila!");
            } else {
                a[N]=0;
                N--;
                System.out.println("El elemento que se ha sacado de la stack es: " + elementoTope);
                }
                return elementoTope;
            }
        
        public static int peek(int[]a, int N){
            int elementoTope = a[N-1];
            System.out.println("El elemento tope de la stack actualmente es: " + elementoTope);
            return elementoTope;
        }
        
        public static int size(int[]a, int N){
            int tamaño = a[N];
            System.out.println("La cantidad de elementos apilados en la stack es : " + tamaño);
            return tamaño;
        }
    }
```

Comment: para declarar una variable estatica ,se pone static int N=0; antes del main

Answer (score 0):

En este metodo estas declarando nuevamente una variable N como parametro es esa variable N la que esta aumentando

```
public static void push(int[]a, int N){
          if (N == a.length){
              a = resize(a,N);
          }
          
          System.out.println("Eligió la opción push. Ingrese el elemento que desea añadir a la stack: ");
          int elementoNuevo=teclado.nextInt();
          a[N]=elementoNuevo;
          System.out.println("Se añadió el elemento " + elementoNuevo + " a la stack.");
          N++;
          
      }
```

Sin embargo al volver aqui

```
int N=0;
    System.out.println("Este programa apila elementos en una stack.");
   
    int[]stack=new int[1];
    String accion;
    boolean continuar = true;
    while (continuar){
        
        accion = preguntarAccion();    
    
        switch(accion){
            case "push": push(stack, N);
                break;
            case "pop": pop(stack, N);
                break;  
            case "peek": peek(stack, N);
                break;   
            case "size": size(stack, N);
                break;   
          
        }
        System.out.println("N vale " + N);
        System.out.println("El stack contiene: " + Arrays.toString(stack));
        continuar = deseaContinuar();
    }
    System.out.println("El programa terminó. Adiós!");
}
```

tu programa se encuentra  otra varible a la cual estas llamada como N y esta iniciada en 0,es por ello que nunca aumentara,si agregas un

```
System.out.println("el valor de "+ N);
```

en el metodo push despues de N++,veras que ese N dentro del metodo push es el que aumenta,entonces cambia el nombre de las variables que tienes como parametro en tus metodos.Entiendo que quieres trabajar el funcionamiento de una pila con arrays,mas no estas implementando una PILA,entonces debes tener en cuenta que tu arreglo stack solo recibe 1 valor